# bash interpreting “!number” as command instead of string in git password

Tags: bash

My password for github has a ! followed by a number. Everytime I run a git command (“username:pass!5word”), gitbash interprets as “which python” (“username:passwhich pythonword”). !# is apparently a command to recall previous arguments. Anyway way around this?

Comment: Can you use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: In bash, `!` is the "recall a command from command history" syntax character. You must protect it from bash's interpolation, e.g., by quoting it as @JoachimIsaksson suggests, or prefixing it with a backslash ``\`` (not to be confused with a normal forward slash `/`). Note that `!<digit>` means the n'th command you ran but `!<string>` is also a history search operation, looking for the given string.

Comment: Try the ascii version of `!` -> `%21`